# How to redirect the user to new webpage after renaming the index page?

Tags: php, html, web, indexing

I am developing a new website.Old name of my website was home.html now i changed it to index.php. when i open the website it is moving to home.html not to index.php. how to solve this problem? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://yoursite.com/index.php">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. i have changed the name of home.html file to index.php. Where i have to update the above meta tage?

Comment: If your idea is that users typing `http://yoursite.com/home.html` gets redirected to `index.php`, the meta goes for your `home.html` since it's the page that gives the order to redirect. So you'll still be having a `home.html` on your server for those who types the old direction (you can make it simple, since it's not actually going to be shown on user's browser), it's also a good idea to put a link to your new page on your `home.php` just in case redirect doesn't work

Comment: You are correct. My doubt is browser should open index.php by default since home.html is not there. why it is still opening the home.html page.

Comment: Well for this method to work, you must still have home.html there too. As I said, a simple html file with just the meta and the optional link. @Tim 's idea is also good, some things are going to depend on which kind of server service you installed

Answer (score 0):

index.php or index.html *should* be the default files loaded by your server when visiting a site, not home.html. Try clearing your cache. If that doesn't help it could be an issue in httpd.conf - but that sounds kind of extreme in this scenario.

You can also look into using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file so the redirect happens at the server level

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect home.html to index.php
RewriteRule ^home.html index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry i am very new to it. could you please help me?

Comment: that command and its location depend on the browser you're using. see this: http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache

Comment: No i having the problem still. Because i dont know how to clear the cache from server side. I cleared the browser history from my browser. Even though it is showing the error. So now i redirec my page from home.html to index.php

Comment: what is the error? perhaps there's something in index.php that's redirecting back to home.html? your question is very vague and you haven't posted any code for us to take a look at.

Comment: my website was having home.html as its index page. Yesterday i renamed it as index.php. So now there is no home.html page. But i tried to open my website. it is www.woodnews.in. When i open my page it is moving to www.woodnews.in/home.html and showing error as file not exist. but it should go to www.woodnews.in/index.php

Comment: Did your hosting company tell you to name it home.html? Perhaps home.html is the default page that's served up by your hosting company? Which would explain why index.php doesn't work. You might want to contact your hosting company about this or look into my mod_rewrite example.

Comment: Ya you are right. i am also thinking the same. i will approach them.